# How to implement value conversion during field comparison operations, in the column type SqlAlchemy (or another class)?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

There are many fields (10+) in different tables, whose logic needs to be encapsulated in the type implementation. For example: upper for string.

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa

class UpperString(sa.String):
    class comparator_factory(sa.String.Comparator):
        def new_sql_operator(self, value: str):
            ...

        # override sql operator
        def match(self, value: str, **kw):
            ...


    def bind_processor(self, dialect):
        """Transform values on db store and query filter parameter on request"""
        def process(value):
            if value is not None:
                value = value.upper()
            return value
        return process

Base = declarative_base(metadata=metadata)

class Name(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'name'
    name = sa.Column('name', UpperString)
    desc = sa.Column('desc', UpperString)
```

How to implement value casting during field comparison operations?

```py
n = Name(name='name')  # new object
assert n.name == 'Name'
n = Name(name='NAME')  # object returning from session.query(Name).filter_by(name='name').one()
assert n.name == 'Name'
```

Similar to the described in the help...

```py
class CaseInsensitiveName(Comparator):
    ...

class Name(Base):
    ...
    @hybrid_property
    def name(self):
        return CaseInsensitiveName(self._name)

    @name.setter
    def name(self, value):
        self._name = value.upper()
```

... but without creating getter/setter for each field and/or model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the code is not clean, but DRY (a simple implementation of custom type inheritance) and work.

Implement processing initiators in the decorator

```py
def operate_comparator(cls):
    class object_processor(Comparator):
        """Transform field value on create model object and parameter on field comparison operations"""
        def operate(self, op, *other, **kwargs):
            other = other[0]
            if not isinstance(other, type(self)):
                other = cls.transform_value(other)
            return op(self.expression, other)

        def __repr__(self):
            return self.expression

    def db_processor(self, dialect=None):
        """Transform field value on db store and query parameter on request"""
        return cls.transform_value

    setattr(cls, 'operate_comparator', object_processor)
    setattr(cls, 'bind_processor', db_processor)
    return cls
```

In a custom type class, you only need to implement a data converter.

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa

@operate_comparator
class UpperString(sa.String):
    class comparator_factory(sa.String.Comparator):
        def new_sql_operator(self, value: str):
            ...

    @staticmethod
    def transform_value(value):
        if value is not None:
            value = value.upper()
        return value
```

Create a type class.
Reassign `field` -> `_field`, for fully automatic creation of properties, it does not work. After `setattr`, the type changes from `InstrumentedAttribute` to `propertyProxy`. Therefore, column in the model class, should be named `_field`, and the created property will be called `field`.

```py
class Name(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'name'
    _name = sa.Column('name', UpperString)
    _desc = sa.Column('desc', UpperString)
```

Dynamically create properties...

```py
def make_property_handler(column_name, column_type):
    def get_(self):
        field = getattr(self, column_name)
        return column_type.operate_comparator(field)

    def set_(self, value):
        value = column_type.bind_processor()(value)
        setattr(self, column_name, value)

    def cmp_(cls):
        field = getattr(cls, column_name)
        return column_type.comparator_factory(field)

    return get_, set_, cmp_


def add_property(model, column, column_type):
    property_name = column[1:]
    if hasattr(model, property_name):
        raise AttributeError(f'Class field with name "{property_name}" is present')
    get_, set_, cmp_ = make_property_handler(column, column_type)
    prop = hybrid_property(get_).setter(set_).comparator(cmp_)
    setattr(model, property_name, prop)
```

...and on the event we attach to the field.

```py
@sa.event.listens_for(Base, 'attribute_instrument')
def configure_listener(model, key, inst):
    if hasattr(inst.property, 'columns'):
        column_type = inst.property.columns[0].type
        if hasattr(column_type, 'transform_value') and key.startswith('_'):
            add_property(model, key, column_type)
```